# Export to excel producing zero (0) byte file

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

I have written a function to export the grid data into excel. When the grid has around 1600 rows, the export function is producing 0byte file. But when the rows are less in numbers, it works fine. My export code is below. I am not getting how/what to debug!! Is this because of Response stream size? Could some one please show me a way, how to proceed with this problem.

```
       Response.Clear();
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "FileName" + ".xls");
       Response.Charset = "";          
       Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
       System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
       System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
       grdMain.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

       Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
       Response.End();
```

Comment: I might have missed it... but what's `Response`? Do you need to flush or close the file properly?

Comment: Is it something as simple as a timeout on the client? The client simply gives up?  You can test this by reading it using System.Net.WebClient to read it instead of a browser - you'll get more fine-tuned control.

Comment: Question seem to be missing ASP.Net or MVC tag... And source missing whole lot of `using` around streams and writers (which may be a reason of the behavior).

Comment: You might be able to further troubleshoot with a tool like Fiddler, to see what's actually going over the wire, status codes, etc. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiddler2.com%2F&ei=PdRpUIDBBeHOyAGx-YG4Bg&usg=AFQjCNGyVxcKeoiBFf3LsfsM8apoKVxKLQ

Comment: I have the try..catch block around the code. But there is no exception caught. The browser saves the file in system, but with no data in it.@Alexei Levenkov I am not sure what you mean by using. You meant for proper namespace?

Comment: He means `using` statements. They handle disposing of any `IDisposable` object automatically after leaving the block of code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Try dropping the following: System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite); 
       grdMain.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

Comment: @iivel : Tried by dropping System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite); grdMain.RenderControl(htmlWrite); , but no use.

Comment: Try to insert `Response.Flush();` just before `Response.End();`.

Comment: Do not put Response.End() inside of a try/catch block or you will get "Thread was being aborted" errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: This is basically what I've suggested in the comments :P.

Comment: Yes, and it's a good answer. Unless he's doing something wrong with control he's rendering, it should fix his problem.

Comment: Perfect!! Response.Flush();, worked for me :). Thank you all for your responses.